# Xamarin Forms ListView Header Sticky for non-grouping

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I've search and found that Sticky Header for ListView are with grouping. Are there any sample ListView with sticky header for non-grouping listview? Could anyone advise me please? Currently I've done as shown below.

```
<ListView.Header>
<Grid BackgroundColor="Gray" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Text="Column 1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Label Text="Column 2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label Text="Column 3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid> </ListView.Header>

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text ="{Binding Item1}" ></Label>
                <Label Text ="{Binding Item2}" ></Label>
                <Label Text ="{Binding Item3}" ></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="{Binding Item4}" ></Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="{Binding Item5}" ></Label>

        </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve the header without using grouping? Just hover over listview like this GIF?https://imgur.com/a/AgKFk6h  If so , you can move your code in ListView.Header to outside the listview like this code.https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/ListLayout

Comment: Thanks. I get it by following the example you provided.

Comment: I post above comment to answer, please mark it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the header without using grouping? Just hover over listview like this GIF?

[image]

If so , you can move your code in ListView.Header to outside the listview like this code

```
<StackLayout>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Text="Column 1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Label Text="Column 2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label Text="Column 3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Grid>

    <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text ="{Binding Data.Name}" ></Label>
                            <Label Text ="{Binding Data.Name}" ></Label>
                            <Label Text ="{Binding Data.Name}" ></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="{Binding Data.Description}" ></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="{Binding Data.Description}" ></Label>

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```